# Flex4 using addElement does not show element properly

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I am using the new Flex4 Spark stuff but I'm stuck at an awful problem. Let me explain a bit of the situation first. I have a container `mx:Canvas` in which I do `addElement()` of one type instances `DocumentWindow`. The document window class is supposed to be the holder for a view according to the type of the document. The `DocumentWindow` class extends `TitleWindow`. I also have a task bar which is a `mx:Canvas` with `buttonBar` inside so that the windows should be switchable. So in 2 words I got windows holder and a taskbar.

The strange thing comes now: When I put a `DocumentWindow` with type "doc" (which loads swf made by swftools) the window appears in the windows holder and as task on the taskbar. But if first I open something else - `DocumentWindow` with type audio or video which causes the `DocumentWindow` to instantiate different view inside, the window doesn't appear on the screen neither a task button is being shown in the `taskBar`. I put a `trace()` on that and it shows that `numElements` is increasing, the `taskBar ButtonBar.dataProvider.length` is increased, so the things are there - just that they stay invisible until I open `DocumentWindow` with type 'doc'?! I even tried to make `DocumentWindow` not to load the view inside because I thought that the only difference is the view... but then even the 'doc' typed `DocumentWindow` didn't show. A clue may be that `creationComplete` is never called until a 'doc' view is added. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Here is a trace I got from the windows holder (There is `numElements` from the windows holder `Canvas` and `ButtonBar.dataProvider.length` from the `taskBar`):

```
1 windows, 1 tasks
    win[0] = (0, 0) - [550, 400], visible=true, alpha=1
1 windows, 1 tasks
    win[0] = (0, 0) - [550, 400], visible=true, alpha=1
1 windows, 1 tasks
    win[0] = (0, 0) - [550, 400], visible=true, alpha=1
1 windows, 1 tasks
    win[0] = (0, 0) - [550, 400], visible=true, alpha=1
1 windows, 1 tasks
    win[0] = (0, 0) - [550, 400], visible=true, alpha=1
```

PS: I `trace()`d also the windows holder size - it's ok, it's big enough :))

Here is the main container code:

```
<s:Group
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:components="some.package.components.*"

    initialize="init()"
    creationComplete="main()">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        public function openDocument(di:DocumentInfo, id:String = null):TaskInfo {
            var w:DocumentWindow = new DocumentWindow();
            var t:TaskInfo = new TaskInfo(di, w, id);
            w.title = di.label;

            var docInfo:DocumentInfo = mServer.getDocumentInfo(di.type, di.label);
            w.init(docInfo, t);

            windows.addWindow(w);
            taskBar.addTask(t);

            return t;
        }

    ]]>
    </fx:Script>



    <mx:HBox id="bottomButtons" horizontalGap="0"
             left="0" bottom="0">
        <mx:Button id="userListButton" click="toggleUserList()"
                   width="40" height="40"/>
        <mx:Canvas id="handButtons"
            horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
            width="40" height="40">
            <mx:Button id="raiseHandButton" click="toggleRaiseHand()"
                       visible="false" width="40" height="40"/>
            <mx:Button id="sitDownButton" click="doSitDown()"
                       visible="false" width="40" height="40"/>
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:HBox>

    <mx:HDividedBox id="vdivider" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="40">
        <components:WindowsView id="windows"/>
        <components:RightPanel id="rightPanel"/>
    </mx:HDividedBox>

    <components:TaskBar id="taskBar"
                        left="{bottomButtons.width}" bottom="0" right="0" height="40"/>

</s:Group>
```

Here is the `WindowsView` class code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

        click="showStuff()"
        width="100%" height="100%">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import some.package.EClassView;

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private function showStuff():void {
                trace(numChildren + ' windows, ' + EClassView.instance.taskBar.taskButtons.dataProvider.length + ' tasks');
                var w:DocumentWindow;
                for(var i:int = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
                    w = getElementAt(i) as DocumentWindow;
                    if(w == null) continue;
                    trace("\twin[" + i + "] = (" + w.x + ", " + w.y + ") - [" + w.width + ", " + w.height + "], visible=" + w.visible + ", alpha=" + w.alpha);
                }
            }

            public function addWindow(w:DocumentWindow):void {
                w.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onWindowCreation);
                addElement(w);
            }

            private function onWindowCreation(e:FlexEvent):void {
                var w:DocumentWindow = e.currentTarget as DocumentWindow;
                w.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onWindowCreation);
                w.center();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xeeeeee" alpha="1"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

</s:Group>
```

The `TaskBar` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

           initialize="init()"
           creationComplete="main()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import some.package.EClassView;
            import some.package.data.TaskInfo;
            import some.package.events.TaskEvent;
            import some.package.skins.GradientButtonSkin;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.core.IVisualElement;
            import mx.core.IVisualElementContainer;
            import mx.events.ItemClickEvent;

            import spark.components.Button;
            import spark.components.DataGroup;
            import spark.components.Group;
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
            import spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarSkin;

            private var mTasks:ArrayCollection;

            public function get tasks():ArrayCollection {
                return mTasks;
            }

            private function init():void {
                mTasks = new ArrayCollection([]);
            }

            private function main():void {
                taskButtons.dataProvider = mTasks;
            }

            public function addTask(task:TaskInfo):void {
                task.index = mTasks.length;
                mTasks.addItem(task);
                task.win.addEventListener("minimize", onWinMinimize);
                task.win.addEventListener("maximize", onWinMaximize);
                task.win.addEventListener("restore", onWinRestore);
                taskButtons.selectedIndex = task.index;
            }

            public function removeTaskAt(i:int):void {
                var task:TaskInfo = mTasks[i] as TaskInfo;
                var evt:TaskEvent = new TaskEvent(TaskEvent.CLOSING);
                task.dispatchEvent(evt);
                if(evt.stopped) return;

                mTasks.removeItemAt(i) as TaskInfo;

                EClassView.instance.windows.removeElement(task.win);
                task.win.removeEventListener("minimize", onWinMinimize);
                task.win.removeEventListener("maximize", onWinMaximize);
                task.win.removeEventListener("restore", onWinRestore);
                rebuildTaskIndexes();
            }

            public function getTaskById(tid:String):TaskInfo {
                for each(var t:TaskInfo in mTasks) {
                    if(t.id == tid) return t;
                }
                return null;
            }

            public function set volume(v:Number):void {
                for each(var t:TaskInfo in mTasks) {
                    t.win.view.setVolume(v);
                }
            }

            private function rebuildTaskIndexes():void {
                for(var n:int = 0; n < mTasks.length; ++n)
                    (mTasks[n] as TaskInfo).index = n;
            }

            private function onWinMinimize(e:Event):void {
                var win:DocumentWindow = e.currentTarget as DocumentWindow;
                win.visible = false;

                var desktop:IVisualElementContainer = win.parent as IVisualElementContainer;
                var nw:DocumentWindow;
                taskButtons.selectedIndex = mTasks.length - 1;
            }

            private function onWinMaximize(e:Event):void {
                var win:DocumentWindow = e.currentTarget as DocumentWindow;
                win.bring2front();

                win.resizable = win.movable = false;
                win.maximized = true;

                var ws:WindowsView = EClassView.instance.windows;
                win.width = ws.width;
                win.height = ws.height;
            }

            private function onWinRestore(e:Event):void {
                var win:DocumentWindow = e.currentTarget as DocumentWindow;
                win.doRestore();
            }

            private function onTaskChanged(e:MouseEvent):void {
                var newt:TaskInfo = mTasks[taskButtons.selectedIndex] as TaskInfo;
                newt.win.doRestore();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:ButtonBar id="taskButtons" requireSelection="true" styleName="taskbar"
                labelField="title" click="onTaskChanged(event)"
                x="0" width="{width - taskButtons.x}" height="100%"/>

</s:Group>
```

And actually the `creationComplete` of the `DocumentWindow` is never being dispatched! I assume the `DocumentView` type 'doc' creates some sort of event which is missing in other views... But the views are too complex to be posted here.. it will be a HUGE post :)

Answer (score 0):

Show us some code, preferably a runnable sample.  But, it sounds like you're mixing MX / Halo components with Spark components.  In Halo components, such as your canvas, you should use addChild, not addElement.

Comment: I can't show the code, unfortunately, because it's too huge and full of networking logic. Anyway I can tell that I already tried both addChild() and addElement - no difference at all. I remind you that not only the windows are invisible but also the buttons of the task bar! Which means the problem seems to somewhere on the way things are getting redrawn, or something like that. I'll try to paste some simplified code ASAP.

Comment: If you really want help, I strongly suggest you turn your code into the smallest possible runnable sample to demonstrate the problem.